# How to convert number to money

Tags: java

I dont know how to convert the "wish money" that i type to numbers will turn into a money format, you can see in the code down there, it will ask me my wish money and then i will type a number 100000 for example i want it to convert it by itself for money format

```
package com.codewitheli;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello matar, Please Enter your wish money");
        String grade = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Your name wish money is: " + grade);
```

Comment: what is money format?

Comment: 1000000> 1,000,000$

Comment: You're inputting a string. You could just add a $ before it if thats all you need. If you want it to become an integer (int) or a float (which are both numbers) you need to parse the string. The Integer and Float classes have methods that do this for you; Integer.parseInt(your_string) and Float.parseFloat(your_string)

Comment: @NewDev Just a heads-up that the dollar symbol should come *before* the amount.  i.e. "$1,000,000", and not "1,000,000$".

Comment: I only started learning it today (java), but i dont understand what do you mean with float or integer, when it asks me "Your wish money is" and i answer with 1000000, i want it to turn into 1,000,000$ after im answering, to tell me Your wish money is: 1,000,000$ after i answer that its 1000000. can u please explain to me where do i locate the command

Comment: @NewDev watch a youtube tutorial or read a book or use an interactive website to learn, it'll help a lot. floats and ints are "number" types for different types of numbers (whole, or decimal, respectively). You could manually make it look how you want, or you can use something like the first answer says.

Comment: I watched some tutorials about primitive types and references, but the one who made tutorial, gives a mission to convert money (after he teached how to do it seperatley) from letters, when answering, to convert it after i answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use something like

```
double amount = scanner.nextDouble()

NumberFormat us     = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
NumberFormat china  = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

System.out.println("US: "     + us.format(amount));
System.out.println("China: "  + china.format(amount));
System.out.println("France: " + france.format(amount));
```

**Complete program:**

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the amount: ");
        double amount = scanner.nextDouble();

        NumberFormat us = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        NumberFormat china = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CHINA);
        NumberFormat france = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE);

        System.out.println("US: " + us.format(amount));
        System.out.println("China: " + china.format(amount));
        System.out.println("France: " + france.format(amount));
    }
}
```

**Sample run:**

```
Enter the amount: 200
US: $200.00
China: ￥200.00
France: 200,00 €
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(1000000);
System.out.println(formatted); //Prints "$1,000,000.00"


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello matar, Please Enter your wish money");
    String grade = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Your name wish money is: " + grade);
```

To integrate it into your code, you'd need to parse the incoming `String` to int:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hello matar, Please Enter your wish money");
    int grade = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your name wish money is: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(grade));
}
```

Comment: it says that it cannot recongize "Locale"

Comment: `import java.util.Locale;`